# How to import framework in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

What is the proper way of importing a system framework in Swift?

There are two ways that I know of, I think.

1) Target->Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries -> + button -> Add your framework. This then adds the framework and shows it graphically in the Navigator.

2) Import Framework in bridging-header.h

In the case of StoreKit framework for example, with method 1) I add it through xCode UI. In method 2) I type in `import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>` in the bridging-header.h

Which one of these is correct in Swift?

Comment: Does `import StoreKit` not work in the class you're using?